# Chucker-Flutter -> why chucker not showing notification

Tags: android, ios, flutter, chucker

I have implemented like this:

```
late final _dio = Dio(
      BaseOptions(
      sendTimeout: const Duration(seconds: 30).inMilliseconds,
      connectTimeout: const Duration(seconds: 30).inMilliseconds,
      receiveTimeout: const Duration(seconds: 30).inMilliseconds,
    ),
  );
```

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _dio.interceptors.add(ChuckerDioInterceptor());
  }
```

```
_dio.get('$_baseUrl$path');
```

Comment: it's working fine actually the notification box is hiding below the keyboard. i have checked in web and mobile also

Answer (score 2):

**Chucker is not working on Android 13+?**

In my case, I have only added

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
```

to manifest.

And I ask permission for this:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
            Permissions.check(requireContext(), arrayOf(
                Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS
            ), null, null,
                object : PermissionHandler() {
                    override fun onGranted() {
                        // Do your business
                    }
                }
            )
        }
```

And all other chucker implementations as before:

build.gradle (module):

```
dependencies {
    ...
    debugImplementation "com.github.chuckerteam.chucker:library:3.5.2"
    releaseImplementation "com.github.chuckerteam.chucker:library-no-op:3.5.2"
    ...
  }

addInterceptor(
            ChuckerInterceptor.Builder(App.instance)
                .collector(ChuckerCollector(App.instance))
                .maxContentLength(250000L)
                .redactHeaders(emptySet())
                .alwaysReadResponseBody(false)
                .build()
        )
```

And that is all!

Comment: Excellent answer! This solved the issue for me.

Comment: Perfectly answered. Worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the app in Release mode or Debug Mode?

Also check if your minSdk version is set to 22 for Android.

Comment: yes I have set the minSdk version to 22 and running in debug mode